# Should a trait be in a separate file?

Tags: php

Assume this situation:

```
interface IFoo
{
  public function Bar();
}

trait Foo
{
  public function Bar()
  {
    echo 'Bar';
  }
}

class FooBar implements IFoo
{
   use Foo;
}

$foobar = new FooBar();
$foobar->Bar(); //echos 'Bar';
```

I put class FooBar in its own file, and interface IFoo also in it own file.

But what should I do with trait Foo:

- In its own file? (my preference)
- Together with the inferface IFoo?
- When the trait is given its own file, how will autoloading deal with that?

note: netbeans marks the code of class FooBar as invalid. Netbeans does not detect that trait Foo is used to implement IFoo. Bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traits are autoloaded just like classes. So if you have a PSR compliant loader (where namespaces are directories, and filenames are class/interface/trait names) everything should work with a trait in it's own file.

So to answer the question in the title, if you wish to stick to standards, then you should use PSR loading, so yes, traits should be in separate files.

As far as netbeans is concerned, I think 7.2 is the only version that supports php 5.4 (and with that, traits), so make sure that you have netbeans 7.2, and that you set php 5.4 in the project settings.

Comment: I have netbeans 7.2, and project settings to php 5.4

Comment: It might be a bug. I'm using 7.2 on ubuntu, and it doesn't complain about the code, although the support for traits could be better. I for instance, don't have autocomplete when using traits.

Comment: If you check out the feature announcement you'll see that as of 7.2, NetBeans can't automatically resolve the namespaces of traits as you type them in the IDE: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/php_5_4_support_traits This seems to still be the case for NetBeans 8.0.x. But you should put traits in separate files, because the whole point is re-using them.